# Spark Submit: Class Not Found Exception

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-submit

I am trying to submit a job to spark on my machine as so:

```
$ spark-submit --master local --class ai.affable.flint.Foo target/scala-2.11/flint.jar
```

However, this fails with the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ai.affable.flint.Foo
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
```

I have verfied that the JAR file exists and has a class called Foo:

```
$ jar tvf ./target/scala-2.11/flint.jar  | grep Foo
2003 Fri Dec 14 20:53:40 MYT 2018 ai/affable/flint/Foo.class
...
```

This baffles me because:
a) the JAR exists b) the class exists in the jar 3) I have specified the fully qualified path and double checked for any path errors or mispellings.

Does anyone know what I am missing?

**EDIT:**

I got it to work by recreating the project in a fresh directory.I literally copy pasted the code and repeated the steps.

I will still like to know what I can do in situations like this short of recreating the project.

Comment: try to specify absolute jar path, not relative path.

Comment: @shay__  Will that help the JVM to find the class in the jar? It as no issues in finding the jar. I confirmed this by changing the path to a non existent jar and seeing a warning in addition to the error above.